# How to get the SHA1 Signing certificate fingerprint?

Tags: air, certificate, sha1, fingerprint

I created a self-signed digital certificate (.p12 / Type: 2048-RSA) with Adobe Air to sign my Android app. How to get the SHA1 signing certificate fingerprint for it?

Comment: [Please don't put tags in the title](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You first need to convert your cert from .p12 (pkcs12) to binary .der (DER) format to achieve this.  The simplest method I can find is to use [this tool](https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-converter.html).

Alternatively, you can do this yourself by first generating a PEM cert and then the DER cert using these commands:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in your_certificate.p12 -out your_certificate.pem
openssl rsa -inform PEM -outform DER -in your_certificate.pem -out your_certificate.der
```

Once you have your DER you can generate the SHA1 like this:

```
openssl dgst -sha1 your_certificate.der
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
keytool -exportcert -keystore [YOUR_CERTIFICATE_PATH] -storepass [YOUR_CERT_PASSWORD]  -list -v -storetype PKCS12
```

Comment: This is the easiest one command without creating additional copies of your secrest _but_ the ommand should read: `keytool  -keystore [YOUR_CERTIFICATE_PATH] -storepass [YOUR_CERT_PASSWORD] -list -v -storetype PKCS12`. The `exportcert` is conflicting.